# android auto emulator on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android-auto

While trying to launch the latest (ver 1.1) Android Auto Desktop Head Unit Emulator from Android SDK and I got error `desktop-head-unit: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. But there is no libssl1.0 in Ubuntu 20 repository, only libssl1.1.
Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210491234

Comment: This is the duplicate question. Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251468/e-package-libssl1-1-has-no-installation-candidate)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this problem:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb
```